# Aiming Rules for Bows in ACKS

Tags: locational-damage, adventurer-conqueror-king

In the core book for ACKS (Adventurer Conqueror King System), there's an example of play that includes a bonus for aiming with a bow.

However, scouring the combat section (and bows under equipment), I cannot find any rules for "aiming". I've also tried the Autarch forums.

Is anyone aware of an official ruling for aiming or even for "called shots" within ACKS?

Comment: Thanks for adding the adventurer-conqueror-king tag.  I couldn't find it.

Comment: Where exactly is this example? Searching the ACKS core book for the word "aim", I find it only in the last paragraph of p13 (talking about the player "aiming" for certain numbers on a die roll) and the description of the Explorer's class abilities on p29 (stating that their "careful aim" gives them a bonus on ranged attack damage).